# Reading SQL Server tables from Azure Synapse notebooks with SparkR

Tags: r, sql-server, azure-synapse

Can't find anything on the above theme. Within Azure Synapse Studio it is possible to use SparkR in notebooks on sparkpools. I have some Azure SQL Server databases that I want to read in the R language
and after having created and manipulated dataframes I want to write the data to a new SQL Server table. How do I proceed ? Is this possible anyway ?
Does anyone have some sample code ?
Thanks!
William

I tried this :
library(SparkR)

#replace<..> with your connection strings
Conn <- "jdbc:sqlserver://appserver06041973.database.windows.net:1433;database=appdb;user=sqladmin;password=XXXXXX!"

Is this correct? What are the statements to read sql server tables in R dataframes from this database and write statements to get the R dataframes in SQL server tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Install `odbc` package using  `install.packages("odbc")`  and run the code below to connect to an SQL database using an R notebook in Synapse:

```
library(odbc)
server <- "dbservere.database.windows.net"
database <- "<databaseName>"
username <- "<userName>"
password <- "<password>"
driver <- "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"
connection_string <- paste0(
  "Driver={", driver, "};",
  "Server=", server, ";",
  "Database=", database, ";",
  "Uid=", username, ";",
  "Pwd=", password
)
connection <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = connection_string)
query <- "SELECT * FROM <tableName>"
result <- dbGetQuery(connection, query)
print(result)
```

This will successfully connect to the database, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: HI, Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm getting an error : Error: [1] "Error in library(odbc): there is no package called ‘odbc’"

Comment: @Billybob49 I have updated my answer you can check there.